# Función JS de una sola linea no se ejecuta , ¿por qué?

Tags: javascript, funciones

tengo una duda con la siguiente función , estoy usando el método find de los array pero supongo que esto es un comportamiento de  las funciones de flecha, el punto es que '**users.find((user) => user.id === id)**' si me muestra el resultado que espero, pero si a esa funcion le coloca las llaves y el doy un salto de linea ya no funciona y me arroja un undefined a pesar de que el código está bien

```
const users = [
  { id: 1, name: 'eduard' },
  { id: 2, name: 'juan' },
  { id: 3, name: 'jose' },
];


const getUser = (id, callback) => {
  const user = users.find((user) => user.id === id);
  console.log(user);
};

getUser(2);
//devuelve: { id: 2, name: 'juan' }
```

si lo coloco así ya no funciona

```
const user = users.find((user) => {
    user.id === id;
  });
//devuelve: undefinded
```

Se que no es necesario poner llaves  si solo es una linea pero  ponerlo tampoco deberia afectar , no es así ?? espero me ayuden a enteder ese pequeño detalle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando haces una función de flecha de una sola linea sin llaves, estas indicando que la funcion retorne el valor que regrese esa primer linea, ejemplo:

```
let funcion = () => 2 + 2
```

retornará 4. Sin embargo:

```
let funcion = () => { 2 + 2 }
```

no retorna nada, si queremos que retorne el resultado de la linea, debemos usar "return":

```
let funcion = () => { return 2 + 2 }
```

En conclusión, Debes escribir:

```
const user = users.find((user) => {
    return user.id === id;
});
```